# Understanding how to control stdout using System.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: c#, .net, doxygen

I see several questions about how to launch processes and push data into stdin, but not how to control where their output goes.

First here is my current code, run from a console mode C# application:

```
    // Prepare the process to run
    ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
    // Enter in the command line arguments, everything you would enter after the executable name itself
    start.Arguments = " -";
    // Enter the executable to run, including the complete path
    start.FileName = "doxygen.exe";
    // Do you want to show a console window?
    start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    start.CreateNoWindow = false;
    start.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    start.UseShellExecute = false;

    // Run the external process & wait for it to finish
    using (Process proc = Process.Start(start))
    {
        //doxygenProperties is just a dictionary
        foreach (string key in doxygenProperties.Keys)
            proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(key+" = "+doxygenProperties[key]);
        proc.StandardInput.Close();
        proc.WaitForExit();

        // Retrieve the app's exit code
        int exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
    }
```

What happens when I run this is I do *not* see any new window (though I think I should) and all of doxygen.exe's stdout is printed to my app's console window.

What I would like to happen is one of two things:

1. Doxygen is launched in a visible window, and I can see its stdout in that window, not in my app's window.
2. Doxygen is launched in a hidden window, and it's stdout is written to a log file.

How can I achieve these?

In addition, why am I not getting a separate window for the spawned process, and why is the spawned process writing output to my window not its own?

Comment: So you didn't notice the `RedirectStandardOutput` property, or the `StandardOutput` property, and you didn't check the documentation of the properties you are setting, such as `CreateNoWindow` which specifically states whether or not a window is shown?  The documentation exists for a reason.  Also, redirecting output is discussed quite a lot; I find it hard to believe you're having ahard time finding discussions on the topic.

Comment: The documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) is terrible. It gives a one-line explanation of each of those things without explaining what they actually mean. For instance why is no new window appearing based on my settings, and why is stdout from the spawned process appearing in my app's window, not its own?

Comment: It's not terrible in the least.  The documentation for [StandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) contains several paragraphs of text, and multiple code examples.  It seems you just assumed the documentation sucked without even looking at it.

Comment: @Servy the docs explain how I can capture the stdout, which answers precisely one part of my question: point 2. I don't see any explanation why the spawned process is writing stdout to my app's stdout without any redirection, or why the spawned app is not showing a new window even though I set `start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal; start.CreateNoWindow = false;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that you can do is use `RedirectStandardOutput` and instead of using `WaitForExit` you can use `ReadToEnd`

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

//make other adjustments to start

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = start;
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

and then you can use `string output` at your leisure

---

If you want to get output in real-time the `p.StandardOutput` property has methods that allow you to get the output asynchronously.  I don't know all the details to it offhand, I've only used it once before,  but there's plenty of literature out there if you search for it.

---

Also be careful when redirecting both `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` at the same time, If they're long enough, it is possible for that to cause deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

1) Indicate that you want the standard output of the process to be directed to your app by setting the [RedirectStandardOuput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) property to true in the process.

2) BEFORE the call to `WaitForExit`, start capturing the output:

```
string sOutput = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

If you do not start reading the output before calling wait for exit, you can encounter a deadlock.

However, it is important to know that standard output will only capture output information, not anything written to the standard error stream of the app.

In order to capture both streams of information, you can hook the process's [OutputDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) and [ErrorDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived.aspx) events and write the event data directly into a log file or store it in a class property for use after the process has completed.